# error: [Errno 111] Connection refused error when sending email in Plone

Tags: exim4

I really have a serious problem on my site and i fixed some of those.
Recently i encountered this error

```
We’re sorry, but there seems to be an error…

Here is the full error message:

Display traceback as text

Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 105, in __call__
Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 130, in __call__
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 324, in __call__
Module Products.PloneHotfix20121106.python_scripts, line 63, in _patched_bindAndExec
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 361, in _bindAndExec
Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
Module script, line 42, in content_status_modify
<FSControllerPythonScript at /clkmis/content_status_modify used for /clkmis/news/news-archive/anti-child-labor-portal-advocates-real-time-monitoring-1>
Line 42
Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 244, in doActionFor
Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 573, in _invokeWithNotification
Module zope.event, line 23, in notify
Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
Module zope.interface.adapter, line 575, in subscribers
Module plone.app.contentrules.handlers, line 189, in workflow_action
Module plone.app.contentrules.handlers, line 132, in execute_rules
Module plone.app.contentrules.handlers, line 99, in execute
Module plone.contentrules.engine.executor, line 27, in __call__
Module plone.contentrules.rule.rule, line 48, in __call__
Module collective.contentrules.mailtolocalrole.actions.mail, line 178, in __call__
Module zope.deprecation.deprecation, line 152, in deprecated_method
Module Products.CMFPlone.patches.securemailhost, line 95, in secureSend
Module Products.MailHost.MailHost, line 342, in _send
Module Products.CMFPlone.patches.sendmail, line 11, in _catch
Module zope.sendmail.mailer, line 46, in send
Module smtplib, line 239, in __init__
Module smtplib, line 295, in connect
Module smtplib, line 273, in _get_socket
Module socket, line 561, in create_connection
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Upon figuring out i found out that i had an ownership problem on /var/log/exim4 and /var/spool/exim4

i fixed this error thru chown -Rv Debian-exim /var/log/exim4 and chown -Rv Debian-exim /var/spool/exim4

Now i was able to send emails thru CLI, but the remaining problem is my plone, i have a content rule that sends email to users if the state of the item is changed and i got the error above, i tried removing the content rule and the changing of state was successful, i really think it's about ownership and permission error since the ownership of /var folder was accidentally altered...

Comment: Your MailHost configuration is connecting to an email server that refuses connections. Fix that configuration. This is not a Plone problem so far.

Comment: user@www:/$ mail username@gmail.com
Subject: hello.
.
Cc: 
Null message body; hope that's ok -> I successfully sent email, btw could it be possible that the cause is about ownership or permission to a file or directory used to send emails?

Comment: On the Plone control panel ('site setup') you'll find an email settings under the 'Mail' header. It tells you the address of the server being used. The command line `mail` command has nothing to do with that.

Comment: it uses root@domain.com, smtp server: localhost on port 25. as far as i know, all mails are forwarded to gmail

Comment: Then you need to fix your SMTP server running on localhost port 25, it is refusing connections.

Comment: Hi martin, i was able to send emails on CLI, does it mean the configuration is correct and the problem is with Plone?

Comment: I am not sure why it happened, everything was fine until i installed hotfix2012 and accidentally changed the owner of /var folder.

Comment: maybe this can help? nslookup -type=ptr 127.0.0.1
Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN

Comment: I also tried, netstat -l --numeric-ports
and sudo netstat -antp | grep LISTEN, but haven't see any port 25 in there.

Comment: and btw i got this error in the mail.log file: tail -f mail.log
Nov 15 07:51:33 www exim4: ALERT: exim paniclog /var/log/exim4/paniclog has non-zero size, mail system possibly broken

Comment: ov 12 13:40:02 www exim[23468]: 2012-11-12 13:40:02 1TXmkc-00066W-4Q Failed to create spool file /var/spool/exim4/input//1TXmkc-00066W-4Q-D: Permission denied
Nov 12 13:40:02 www exim[23468]: 2012-11-12 13:40:02 1TXmkc-00066W-4Q Cannot open main log file "/var/log/exim4/mainlog": Permission denied: euid=101 egid=103
Nov 12 13:40:02 www exim[23468]: exim: could not open panic log - aborting: see message(s) above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Changed the owner of /var/log/exim4/ and /var/spool/exim4 to Debian-exim

chown chown -Rv Debian-exim.Debian-exim /var/log/exim4
chown chown -Rv Debian-exim.Debian-exim /var/spool/exim4